# Kafka Streams : Sharing globalStateStore across topologies

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a Spring boot application that uses Processor API to generate a Topology and also a addGlobalStateStore to the same topology.

I want to create another topology (and hence another KafkaStreams) for reading from another set of topics and want to share the previously created store in the new topology. By share I mean that the underlying state store should be the same for both topologies. Any data written from one topology should be visible in the other.

Is that possible without writing wrapper endpoints to access the state store e.g. REST calls?

Or does my usecase need an external state store e.g. redis?

Comment: I don't think you can share state stores between topologies. But rather you would have to merge both topologies into a single one.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't share the state stores across topologies. Instead if possible, you can break down your topologies as sub-topologies and that will make it available across all the processors defined.

If that is not possible for you, you can use external storage.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Stream Partitions and Tasks](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#stream-partitions-and-tasks):

> Sub-topologies (also called sub-graphs): If there are multiple
> processor topologies specified in a Kafka Streams application, each
> task only instantiates one of the topologies for processing. In
> addition, a single processor topology may be decomposed into
> independent sub-topologies (or sub-graphs). A sub-topology is a set of
> processors, that are all transitively connected as parent/child or
> via state stores in the topology. Hence, different sub-topologies
> exchange data via topics and don’t share any state stores. Each task
> may instantiate only one such sub-topology for processing. This
> further scales out the computational workload to multiple tasks.

This means that sub-topologies (hence topologies too) can't share any state stores.

Solution for your scenario:

create a single `KafkaStreams` instance with its topology containing everything you otherwise would put in your 2 distinct topologies. This will determine the creation of a single [task](https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/architecture#streams_architecture_tasks) for the entire topology (because of that store usage); there'll be no sub-topology because you are using a store used by both initially distinct topologies. This also means that the entire topology can be run by a single thread only (this is the main drawback), can't be splitted in sub-topologies to be run by multiple threads - this doesn't mean that the topology as a whole can't be run by multiple threads depending on the chosen parallelism ([num.stream.threads](https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#num-stream-threads)).